# Pyinstaller Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I converted the py script to exe using pyinstaller but when I try to run the exe I got this. How can I fix it?
[image: Error image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell pyinstaller what modules it need to bundle in the program, so, in your case, you have to pass as hidden import this: `pkg_resources`

In the .spec file that generated after running the pyinstaller, you will find an option like this:

```
hiddenimports=[]
```

Put it like this:

```
hiddenimports=["pkg_resources"]
```

Then, run pyinstaller like this:

```
pyinstaller app.spec
```

Or, if you still want to run it trought the .py, pass it as parameter like

```
pyinstaller app.py --hidden-import pkg_resources
```

Normally, if your program its more than a "Hello world", this is going to be a few more modules, you just need to add them all to hiddenimports as a list until there is no more `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Remember to **NOT run pyinstaller to the .py file** if you modified the .spec file, as it will create a new one and overwrite it, ignoring the previous.

You have to execute pyinstaller with the .spec file

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Sebastian which is passing the module to hidden import do solve the problem too. I happen to found another solution while waiting for the answers, just have to reinstall pyinstaller which I `pip install pyinstaller` initially

To uninstall the pyinstaller:

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

To install pyinstaller again:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Comment: Note here that you are installing the last developer code of pyinstaller and not the last stable one (currently 3.6), so might have other problems