# Failed to Execute Script pyi_rth_win32api [Tkinter - Pyinstaller]

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I prepared an .exe file using pyinstaller, Pyton 3 and Tkinter. However, when I try to start .exe file I got an error like image below.

I tried these solutions
[Pyinstaller Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926929/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres)
but both answers do not solve the problem.

Does anyone who knows how can I fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the command used by you to create the exe? Ideally the accepted answer of the linked post should have solved it. You can try adding this hidden import `pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn example.py`.

Comment: I looked at the warnings which were shown at the console while creating the .exe file. I saw "WARNING: lib not found: pywintypes39.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd". I added C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages to the path. pyinstaller -wF example.py command works now. I saw your message after I solved the problem via that way. My problem solved for now so, I did not try your solution. Maybe someone will stuck again and solve the problem with your suggestion. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Okay alright, you can consider answering your own question if you have found the solution, it might help future visitors.

Comment: AST, thank you. You answer solved my problem. It should be the solution.